# Retrieve Social Landing Pages with GA Reporting API V4

Tags: google-analytics-api

In the Google Analytics Reporting API V4, the [Social Activities Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=social_activities) are deprecated. Unfortunately **Shared URL** (`ga:socialActivityContentUrl`) is one of these.

How can I retrieve **Acquisition > Social > Landing Pages** report data through this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with some help from the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).

Query on dimension `ga:landingPagePath` (and optionally `ga:hostname`, if relevant) and filter to include where `ga:hasSocialSourceReferral` equals `"Yes"`.

To exactly match, add an `AND` filter with the `NOT` flag set to exclude where `ga:landingPagePath` equals `"(not set)"`.

**NOTE:** API results may be sampled (check `samplesReadCounts`). You may need to issue multiple queries for smaller date ranges and aggregate.